# "sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be uid 0" message, but sudo works fine

Tags: terminal, mojave, permission, user-account, sudo

Running Mojave on a MBP 2012 13" and I get that message every time I use the sudo command. It isn't preventing me to use sudo, but I get the feeling it'll bite me in the butt at some point in time, and rather have it fixed now then later.

I have tried many of the solutions from other questions asked before but none of them remove the message. I have two account, my main with my name, and an administrator account I used for a work around to get my account admin permissions (it was so long ago I forgot what the problem was before). Both of them can use sudo.

When I run an ls -ln command with sh I only get a ts account listed.

```
drwx------  3 0  0  96 May 27 12:40 ts
```

And an ls -la command gives me only one account with an account name I know I've made before, but don't remember where exactly.

```
drwx--x--x    3 brushie  wheel    96 Sep 24  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x  106 root     wheel  3392 May 27 10:21 ..
drwx------    3 root     wheel    96 May 27 12:40 ts
```

I've heard you should see your account somewhere in both of these lists, I'm pretty sure my issues are here but I don't know how to go about fixing it without screwing something up.

Comment: Where are you running those `ls` commands? What do they have to do with `sudo`?

Comment: Inside of "/var/db/sudo/"